# Export deployed SSIS package from SQL Server 2008 to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, etl, ssis-2008

There are ETL Packages that have been deployed to SQL 2008. I want to export these back to SSIS 2008 to update the package. For some reason it is not working. Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export it from SSQL Server:

SSMS:
Integration Services Catalogs -> SSISDB -> Project -> Right click on project -> Export -> Save the `ispac` file

Visual Studio:
New -> Project -> Integration Services Import Project Wizard -> Select Project deployment file  -> use file from step 1

Comment: Doesn't SSIS 2008 require using BIDS 2008?  I thought SSDT didn't come out until 2012.  Its been a while so I'm not certain.  In addition, 2012 introduced the Project deployment model.  I don't recall if ispac was available in the file deployment model used in 2008.

Comment: @WesH That may be right. I do not have such instance to even check it(SQL Server 2008 is EOL).